# Configuring ELMAH in Machine.config - 404 on elmah.axd

Tags: c#, .net, logging, error-handling, elmah

I'm trying to get elmah up and running on my entire website. I first configured it in the localhost website web.config using assembly references, as I put elmah in the gac, and made sure it all worked fine, and I get both an email and can access http://localhost/elmah.axd.

Now, I copy all of the elmah sections of the config file to:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config

And then I remove the web.config file of the website. Now when I go to localhost/elmah.axd I get a 404, but I also get the 404 in from elmah by mail?

What's wrong with the httphandler? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Why didn't you change `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config` instead?

Comment: -.- I read in the guide it should be in the machine.config - I just added the elmah.axd handler to the web.config file it works - thanks very much - could you make a quick answer for me to accept? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ELMAH HTTP handler configuration should be in the `web.config` file.

Comment: For those of you trying to get this to work in IIS7 it's a bit different.  See this post answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9948356/5496