# Problem with Elmah in the GAC

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I am attempting to follow this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/elmahGAC.aspx

to get Elmah working from the GAC rather than needing to be setup for each application individually. Everything works locally but when the settings are set globally, Elmah stops logging. I read somewhere that if Elmah is running from the GAC then the settings should be in the "global" machine.config vs the "global" web.config but I've tried both. Right now, I'm at a point where if I add this:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abc123" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

into my application's web.config, it picks up the rest of the settings from the global machine.config and logs successfully. To answer the obvious question, yes I have this section in the global machine.config and have even tried entering it in the global web.config but still logging won't work. Anyone have any ideas? Is there anyway to get Elmah to display its errors instead of failing quietly?

EDIT: Here is my "global" machine.config file. It's just the default one with the stuff for ELMAH added and some section groups taken out to meet the char limit. I should probably also note this is running in IIS7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>


<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

<connectionStrings>
<clear />
<add name="Elmah.Sql"      connectionString="IMNOTTELLING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="IMNOTTELLING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" />      
</elmah>

<runtime />



<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories />
</system.data>

<system.serviceModel>
Nothing tampered with here
</system.serviceModel>



<system.web>
    <processModel autoConfig="true"/>

  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
  </httpHandlers>

  <httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
  </httpModules>

  <compilation>
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>

    <membership>
    Nothing tampered with here
    </membership>

    <profile>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/"
                type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager>
        Nothing tampered with here
    </roleManager>
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests ="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e50dbdd41da277ac" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: I installed the modules and handler in IIS directly and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with IIS7 on a Win7x64 install (testing for a production system).  I finally got this working by putting the module and handler into the appropriate nodes in the `applicationHost.config` file.

`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

It seems that IIS7 ignores certain areas of the main framework `web.config` files, instead using the `applicationHost.config` file for IIS settings.

Something to note about that file if you are on a 64 bit install: it seems that 32 bit applications (including Visual Studio) will appear to not see the file.  It's because of some file system behavior due to the OS being 64 bit.  One easy work around is to open it using an UNC path:

`\\localhost\c$\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt the PublicKeyToken of Elmah is **abc123**... You need to use the real PublicKeyToken, which you can find if you look at the assembly in the GAC. It looks something like: b03f5f7f11d50a3a (that was for mscorlib.dll, so that is Microsoft's public key token).

Comment: It doesn't matter which file you put the module declaration in, as long as it is in the system.WebServer/modules section. Does it work if you put the DLL in the bin folder of the app?

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with the DLL being in GAC or not, then... What does Fusion Log Viewer tell you if you empty your Temporary ASP.NET Files first?

Comment: It came up blank. The assembly is definitely working from the GAC. It just requires that blurb of code at the application level to be functional. That to me points to a problem somewhere in the "global" machine.config or web.config files but I don't know what... Thank you very much for the help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I installed the modules and handler in IIS directly and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything I could find to get ELMAH working from the GAC on my Win7 Ultimate 64bit  machine and the only thing that finally got it working was registering the elmah.axd handler and the various modules in IIS Manager.